# What's the difference between Fréchet-differentiation and complex differentiation "intuitively"?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be open in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a funtion.

Define $H\triangleq \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x+iy\in G\}$.

Define $u(x,y)=Re(f(x+iy))$ and $v(x,y)=Im(f(x+iy))$ for all $(x,y)\in H$.

Assume that $u,v$ are Fréchet differentiable at a point $(X,Y)$ and they do **not** satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equation

> Is there a case $f$ is not complex-differentiable in this case? And why this is possible intuitively?

Set $T=Du(X,Y)+ i Dv(X,Y)$. Then,we have $T(a,b)=au_x(X,Y) + bu_y(X,Y) + i( av_x(X,Y) + bv_y(X,Y))$.

Thus, $|f(X+iY + (h+ik)) - f(X+iY) - hu_x(X,Y) - ku_y(X,Y) - i hv_x(X,Y) -ikv_y(X,Y))|= o(h+ik) \cdots (1)$

Also,note that $|f(X+iY + (h+ik)) - f(X+iY) - (h+ik)f'(X+iY)|=o(h+ik) \cdots (2)$ **if $f$ is differentiable**.

So both expressions are approximations of $f(z)$ near $X+iY$. But $(1)$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ approximation and $(2)$ is $\mathbb{C}$ approximation.

But if $u,v$ do not satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equation, what kind of approxnation is $(1)$? I tried to draw a diagram to compare, but I cannot figure out how they are different.

(**Note**: "If $f$ is differentiable, then $u,v$ satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equation. Hence $u,v$ must satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equation to have $f$ differentiable." I know this! But I'm not asking this analytically. )

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally, $\mathbb C$-differentiable is a more stringent requirement than $\mathbb R^2$-differentiable.  Note that they are both Fréchet, except the latter uses *all* linear operators on $\mathbb R^2$ as candidates for the derivative (in the Taylor expansion that you've written above) wheras the first one uses only linear operators on $\mathbb R^2$ that *represent* complex numbers, i.e., linear conformal transformations, i.e., angle preserving, i.e., matrices of the form $$\begin{bmatrix}\phantom-a&b\\-b&a\end{bmatrix}\text{ with }a,b\in\mathbb R.$$

Answer (score 0):

Think of the function $\mathbb C\ni z\mapsto \bar z\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: Hint: this is a $\mathbb R$-linear operator on $\mathbb R^2$, but not a $\mathbb C$-linear operator on $\mathbb C$ (which is $\mathbb R$-linearly isomorphic to, but more structured than, $\mathbb R^2$.)